# Decent implementation of DAG in PHP?

Tags: php, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there some available PHP implementations out there of directed acyclic graph ? I've found DRUPAL's (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Graph%21Graph.php/8) but it's not really helpful (I want to add/delete nodes as well). Any suggestions ?

Comment: Btw the link you have given is a bit slow, barely loads...

Answer (score 4):

Look at this article, it might be of help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, zigi ! But I've already seen this and it's not the model I'm having trouble with. It's the DAG implementation itself. I haven't written DFS before and it's quite a hassle for me. Anyway, if nothing comes out soon I'll just try to do it myself. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

There is a new structure in PHP 7.

You can check the implementation here:
https://github.com/graphp/graph

Comment: This library is built around the concept of mathematical graph theory (i.e. it is not a charting library for drawing a graph of a function). In essence, a graph is a set of nodes with any number of connections in between. In graph theory, vertices (plural of vertex) are an abstract representation of these nodes, while connections are represented as edges. Edges may be either undirected ("two-way") or directed ("one-way", aka di-edges, arcs).